# How to handle nested jquery deferred calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, jquery-deferred

I have a function to get some data, and the function should return a promise. In the function, I have to made 2 requests - one after another. I ended up with a nested deferrer call where the last call `resolves` on the deferrer the function will return. I'm new to this deferred stuff and wonder if this is the right solution.

```
function getData(func) {
    var model = new Model();
    var collection = new Collection();
    var dfd = new jQuery.Deferred();

    collection.fetch().then(function () {
        model.fetch().then(function () {
            dfd.resolve(collection);
        });
    });

    return dfd.then(function (collection) {
        return getViews(func(collection), model);
    });
}
```

Comment: I may have found a bug with your question and the accepted answer.  Both code returns getViews() within the .then() callback.  It's important conceptually to understand the getData() function returns the .then() deferred, NOT the getView() deferred.  Returning the getViews() is doing nothing here.  If you have other code using this getData(), like additional .then() calls, you won't be guaranteed the getViews will be complete.  You are only guaranteed it will have started.  See the problem?  Just something to be aware of.

Comment: So would be returning `$.when().done()` a solution here?

Comment: @cereal77killer, your assertion that "returning the getViews() is doing nothing here" is (from jQuery 1.8) incorrect. The inner `return` is included expressly to make the promise returned by `getData()` behave the way you want it to. In other words, if you were to chain `.then()` to the promise returned by `getData()`, you **will** be guaranteed that `getViews()` is complete. If you don't believe me, then read the paragraph starting "As of jQuery 1.8" [here](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/). Using `.done()` would give the behaviour you very correctly seek to avoid.

Comment: You are absolutely correct.  I've been switching between code bases with 1.7 and 2.0 in a couple projects and must of assumed it was pre 1.8.  Sorry!

Comment: @cereal77killer, yes, it's a great pity that jQuery implemented that ghastly non-standard `.then()` from 1.5 to 1.7. Must have confused millions of us.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Andreas, I see you have quite correctly accepted Vitaliy's answer and I'm not trying to steal his points but just in case you are not aware, there's no need to create and resolve your own `$.Deferred()` and there's no need to pass `collection` around (except to `func()`) as it remains in scope.

As far as I can tell from the code in the question, the following should work :

```
function getData(func) {
    var collection = new Collection();
    var model = new Model();
    return $.when(collection.fetch(), model.fetch()).then(function() {
        return getViews(func(collection), model);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If the order of the calls does not matter I would suggest to use http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when

With `when` you can make parallel xhr requests.